# How to handle form select options that change over time?

Tags: symfony, symfony4

In a symfony 4 project I have a form that where a user can record a "presenter" from a `select` list. The options for the `select` list are pulled from a `Staff` entity using a query in my FormType:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('presenter', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => Staff::class,
            'placeholder' => 'Select presenter',
            'query_builder' => function (StaffRepository $repo) {
                return $repo->createAlphabeticalQueryBuilder()
                    ->andWhere('staff.isPresenter = true');
            },
        ])
        ->add('other fields...')
}
```

Over time, the `Staff` members who are presenters change. The problem I have is that if I have a record where "other fields" have to be updated at a later time but the `Staff` member is no longer a "presenter", then the previous presenter is not even an option in the `select` list. When the form is submitted, the previous presenter is then lost (the `presenter` is now captured as NULL).

How can I preserve the presenter in a case like this?

Comment: You can add unmapped field for presenter for form and change the mapped one in edit-process only when theres new value and ignore case when theres original value but new one is NULL? Or you can pass the choices to your formtype as all from StaffRepo merged with that one he has right now?

Comment: @Eakethet, great idea about the unmapped field. I'll give that a try.